# public domain poker images

Tags: texas-hold-em

I'm making a poker hand replayer. Does anyone know where I can get public domain images to use? I already have cards but I need chips and the table, or ideally an open source html5 hand replayer that I can plug into my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many free vector graphic websites. I find these two the most reliable and extensive:

1. [1001freedownloads.com](http://www.1001freedownloads.com/)
2. [www.freevectors.net](http://www.freevectors.net/)

Alternatively, you could opt to [hire a freelancer](https://www.freelancer.com/u/BenchmarkDev.html) on a website such as https://www.freelancer.com/ or https://www.fiverr.com/. Where you can get exactly what you want designed for very reasonable prices. Hiring a freelancer means that you will own the rights and not have to worry about copyright etc. Whereas in some cases a reference is required for some resources from 'free' sites.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many public domain images website. I found one of the useful website is http://www.publicdomainbox.com/. Here you can checkout Wide variety of Public Domain images, free stock photos, royalty free images.Hope this will be helpful for you.